# How to send a file from C to Java via tcp/ip and receive the same file from Java to C without data loss and other errors?

Tags: java, c, file, sockets, tcp

How do I send a text file from C to Java and receive the same file back from Java to C, without data loss? The code is below for reference.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int send_text(int socket) { 
    FILE *text;
    char a[50];
    int size, read_size, stat, packet_index;
    char send_buffer[8008], read_buffer[8008];
    int wrt=0,sock_fd,tsize=0;
    packet_index = 1;
    int i=0; 
    text = fopen("/home/sosdt009/Desktop/character3.txt", "r"); 
    if (text == NULL) {
        printf("Error Opening text File:");
        exit(-1);
    }  
    printf("Getting text Size:\n");
    gets(a);
    fseek(text, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(text);
    fseek(text, 0, SEEK_SET);
    printf("Total text size: %d \n", size);    
    gets(a);

    //Send text Size

    printf("Sending text Size:\n",size);
    gets(a);
    send(socket, (void *)&size, sizeof(size), 0);

    /*do {     
      stat = recv(socket, read_buffer, 1024, 0);
      }*/while(stat < 0)
    printf("Socket data:%s \n", read_buffer); 
    gets(a);   
    while(size>tsize) {
        //Read from the file into our send buffer
        read_size = fread(send_buffer,1,sizeof(send_buffer),text);
        printf("The size of send buffer:%c \n",send_buffer);
        gets(a);
        printf("The read size value is :%d \n", read_size);
        gets(a);

        //Send data through our socket 

        do
        {            
            stat = send(socket, send_buffer, read_size, 0);
            printf("The send size value is: %d \n", size);
            gets(a);
            printf("The read size value is: %d \n", read_size);
            gets(a);

        } while (stat < 0); 
        printf("Packet %d, sent %d bytes.\n", packet_index, read_size);
        gets(a);

        //packet_index++;
        //Zero out our send buffer

        tsize = tsize+read_size;
        printf("The tsize value is:%d \n",tsize);
        gets(a);
        memset(send_buffer,0, sizeof(send_buffer));

        if(read_size<=NULL)
        {
            printf("The connection is transferred to received text: \n");
            gets(a);
        }
    }
    fclose(text);
    //close(socket);
    printf("Text successfully send:\n");
    gets(a);
    return 0;   
}

int receive_text(int socket)
{ 
    int buffersize = 77,recv_size=0,read_size = 1, write_size,size; 
    char *pBuf,a[50],b[77]; 
    int errnom,i;
    FILE *textnew; 
    size_t rec;
    textnew = fopen("/home/sosdt009/Desktop/receivednew.txt", "a");    
    if (textnew == NULL)   
    {      
        printf("Error has occurred, text file could not be opened \n");
        return -1;
    }

    //Loop while we have not received the entire file yet

    while(read_size > 0)
    {

        ioctl(socket, FIONREAD, &buffersize);
        printf("The Buffersize is    :%d\n",buffersize);
        gets(a);
        printf("The size of socket is:%d\n",socket);
        gets(a);

        //We check to see if there is data to be read from the socket 

        if (buffersize > 0)
        {
            printf("Buffersize value is  :%d\n", buffersize);
            gets(a);
            pBuf = malloc(buffersize);
            if (!pBuf)
            {
                printf(errnom, "Memory Error Cannot Allocate!\n");
                gets(a);
                exit(-1);
            }

            //read_size = read(socket,pBuf,buffersize);
            //read_size = fread(pBuf,buffersize,1,textnew);

            read_size = recv(socket,pBuf,sizeof(pBuf),1);
            //memset(pBuf,'\0',sizeof(pBuf));
            printf("Read size value is :%d \n",read_size);
            gets(a);
            printf("Buffersize value is:%d \n",sizeof(pBuf));
            gets(a);

            /*if (read_size < 0)
              {
              printf("%d\n",strerror(errno));
              printf("Data not written to the file:\n");
              gets(a);
              goto free;
              }*/

            //Write the currently read data into our text file

            //write_size = write(textnew,read_size,pBuf);                        //using write function
            write_size = fwrite(pBuf,1,read_size,textnew); 
            free(pBuf);
            printf("Write size value is   :%d \n",write_size);
            gets(a);
            printf("Buffer size value is  :%d \n",sizeof(pBuf));
            gets(a);            

            //Increment the total number of bytes read

            recv_size += read_size;
            printf("Received size value is:%d \n",recv_size);
            gets(a);
            printf("Read size value is    :%d \n",read_size);       
            gets(a);    
        }
    }
free:
    fclose(textnew);
    close(socket);   
    printf("Text Successfully Received:\n");
    gets(a);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char *parray,errnomu;

    //Create socket

    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(socket_desc == -1) 
    {
        printf("Could not create socket \n");
    }
    memset(&server,0,sizeof(server));
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.170.0.38");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(6999); 

    //Connect to remote server

    if (connect(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0) 
    {

        printf(strerror(errnomu));                     
        printf("Connect Error \n");
        return -1;         
    }

    puts("Connected");
    send_text(socket_desc);
    receive_text(socket_desc);
    close(socket_desc);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Can you describe what is not working as expected?

Comment: I am able to receive null values in the file with very few characters.

Comment: You've mentioned Java without posting any Java code.

Comment: In java there is no error, i have checked with one of my friend who is working in java.

Comment: You must consider the possibility that your friend is wrong. Post the Java code. This C code is also wrong to loop while `stat < 0`, and to compare an integer to NULL, among other things, but that won't cause the problem you describe.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a complete meal of this. You don't need all the fseeks and ftells and do/whiles and nested loops. The do/while in particular is quite mad. Keep doing something while there is an error?

I don't recommend you use stdio for reading the file. It adds nothing of value here and just makes the code more complex than it needs to be.

The standard way to copy a file descriptor in C is as follows:

```
while ((count = read(infd, buffer, sizeof buffer)) > 0)
{
    write(outfd, buffer, count);
}
if (count == -1)
{
    perror("read");
}
// close them both
```

If this is a fair sample of your C coding it is impossible to share your friend's confidence in your Java code.

The standard Java copy loop is as follows:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
// close them both
```